# Add line breaks or spaces between elements when using jQuery .append()

Tags: jquery, append, line-breaks, dom-manipulation, css

I have a jQuery set of elements that I get from my DOM by calling:

```
$(".some-selector");
```

All my elements are DIVs each in its own line. My DIVs are set CSS (among other things)

```
display: inline-block;
```

which prevents them from rendering as block elements (each in its own line).

The problem is that when these DIV are rendered they have spaces between them because there's line break in the document between each element. I'm comfortable with that. I could of course use `float:left` that would get rid of these spaces but that's not what I want because I would have other problems with container sizing etc.

So. The problem is that I manipulate the order of these elements in my jQuery set an then rerender them. What I essentially do is:

```
$(".some-selector").detach().manipulate().appendTo(".container");
// or equivalent
$(".container").append($(".some-selector").detach().manipulate());
```

The problem is that they get re-inserted into the DOM, but without line breaks or spaces...

**How do I get these line breaks back in when appending my elements into DOM?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After you re-insert your elements, append some whitespace to each of them using [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after):

```
$(".some-selector").after(" ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5cFw/

Comment: That doesn't work - there is no space between the SPAN elements: http://jsfiddle.net/u5jBS/1/

Comment: @Šime: It works, but his example is using `.append()` instead of `.after()` like in the ansewr. http://jsfiddle.net/z5cFw/

Comment: I suppose it's better to have the bug in the jsfiddle than in the posted answer, right? :-)  Thanks for fixing the jsfiddle!

Comment: This works although I understood jQuery documentation incorrectly when it says: *One or more additional DOM elements, arrays of elements, HTML strings, or jQuery objects to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.* I thought it's going to append it after each element because I was appending a set to an element while documentation is actually referring to appending an element to a set. :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `map` to put a single-space TextNode after each DIV:

```
$('.some-selector').detach().manipulate().map(function() {
    return [this, document.createTextNode(' ')];
}).appendTo('.container');
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hnv2T/

Comment: This really is a clever one Šime. +1 from me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Šime's code has a caveat: it also adds a space after the last element.

Here is a version that avoids that space:

```
$('.some-selector').detach().manipulate().map(function (index, element) {
    return index === 0 ? element : [document.createTextNode(' '), element];
}).appendTo('.container');
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tqx19m3L/